# In IDA is there a way to load the PE headers after the initial loading?

Tags: ida, pe

*This* question is loosely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70982549/476371). So I know of manual loading and how to achieve loading the PE headers using it.

But suppose I have already worked on an IDB for a while and realize that there are code references back to the PE headers, so I'd like to revise my initial decision (it's what I've always done so far ... sort of cargo-culting).

Any way of doing this, short of exporting my work up until now into an `.idc` and starting over?

Comment: Please also note that typically applying an `.idc` to an IDB that has been differently loaded can be ... tricky. So it tends to be a lossless process, which is why I'd prefer to treat my existing IDB this way.