# Is "PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = YES" synonymous with "Load resources" from the "Load a new file" dialog?

Tags: ida

As per [this recent blog article](https://hex-rays.com/blog/igors-tip-of-the-week-122-manual-load/) one can set the PE loader to default to loading all sections. I even knew that. So setting the following setting in `cfg\pe.cfg` does the trick:

```
PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = YES
```

I often find myself needing to load at least the file header ([sometimes in hindsight](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/30389/245)) but there is no explicit option for the file header on the load dialog:

[image: Load new file dialog]

Instead we have the "Load resources" checkbox, which -- if checked -- avoids having to do a full manual load, but seems to load *both* the resources (`.rsrc` "segment") and the file header (`HEADER` "segment").

[image: List of segments]

That *also* seems to be the effect of configuring `PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = YES`. Alas, if you set the configuration inside the `cfg\pe.cfg`, the "Load resources" checkbox doesn't get default-checked or so.

So my question is: are these two methods to load the file header and resources synonymous? If not, are they overlapping? What are the differences?

---

#### Experiment: trying all combinations on handle46.exe from SysInternals

Here's the outcome of the various settings on a PE file with IDA Pro 8.2.221215:

1. `PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = NO` (default) and *no changes* on the load dialog:
   [image: Just: PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = NO]
2. `PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = NO` (default) and "[✔] Load resources" on the load dialog:
   [image: Load resources AND PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = NO]
3. `PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = YES` and *no changes* on the load dialog:
   [image: Just: PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = YES]
4. `PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = YES` and "[✔] Load resources" on the load dialog:
   [image: Load resources AND PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = YES]

The odd outcome is 3., because it loads the `.rsrc` section although it hadn't been asked for it. That's also the reason why I asked this question in the first place.

Comment: I don't see `3` as an odd case. What you have is 2 different methods to change the behavior of IDA. Setting `PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = YES` in the config file does what it says, loads all sections (including `.rsrc`). Checking `Load resources` in the GUI also does what it says, ensures that `.rsrc` is loaded. These 2 configuration methods are independent of each other.

Comment: Just to clarify, these 2 methods only make changes when they are set to `YES` or checked. When they're set to `NO` or unchecked, they do nothing.

Comment: I guess they are indeed independent of each other. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only get the `HEADER` segment when `PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS` is set to `YES` in `cfg\pe.cfg`.

Checking `Load Resources` with `PE_LOAD_ALL_SECTIONS = NO` only adds the `.rsrc` segment for me (7.6 SP1).